# How to coerce functors applied to coercible arguments

Tags: haskell, type-conversion

Consider the following Haskell code:

```
import Data.Coerce

newtype Decorated s a = Decorated a

fancyFunction :: Ctx s => f (Decorated s a) -> r
fancyFunction = ...

instance Ctx s => SomeClass (Decorated s a)

myFunction :: Functor f => f a -> r
myFunction = fancyFunction . fmap coerce
```

I'd like to make `myFunction` faster by replacing `fmap coerce` with `coerce`. The rationale is that `coerce` behaves like `id` and one of the functor laws is `fmap id = id`.

The only way I can see of doing this is to add `Coercible (f a) (f (Decorated s a))` to the context but it refers to s which is not referred to anywhere else. Even worse, if `a` is bound in a universal type, I cannot express the constraint. Is there a constraint I could express in terms of `f` only to let me use `coerce` to convert between `f a` and `f (Decorated s a)`?

Is this something that the compiler figures out on its own from the fact that `f` is a functor? If so, does it also work with bifunctors, traversables and bitraverables?

Comment: `myFunction` already doesn't compile, because the type `s` is not mentioned (as you have pointed out) in the type of the function, so `Ctx s` arising from `fancyFunction` results in an ambiguous type error (even `fancyFunction . undefined` gives such an error). In any case it sees you want a function `(Functor f, Coercible a b) => f a -> f b` which is operationally the identity, in which case you may be interested in [profunctors](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/profunctors-5.2/docs/Data-Profunctor-Unsafe.html#v:-35-.) - this uses 'unsafe' operations in general but as GHC will tell you..

Comment: "NB: We cannot know what roles the parameters to \`f' have; we must assume that the role is nominal " if you fix the unrelated ambiguous type error (by e.g. removing the `Ctx s` constraint). There is no way to talk about the role of a type variable - this is a known limitation.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no way around this. The problem is that what you want to do can or cannot be done depending on the role of whatever `f` is. [This](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/9123) ticket goes into more detail. [Here](https://github.com/ekmett/roles/blob/master/src/Data/Roles.hs) is one of Edward Kmett's alternative approaches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, `Coercible (f a) (f (Decorated s a))` really what you want in your constraint given the current state of GHC. Now, the fact that `s` and `a` don't show up elsewhere is not something good - it means GHC won't know what to do with them (they are ambiguous)! I won't get into that...

---

Depending on the [role](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#roles) of the type parameter fed to the type constructor `f`, `Coercible a b` may or may not imply `Coercible (f a) (f b)`. In this case, we'd want that role to be nominal - but there isn't (yet at least) a way to express this in a constraint. To explain what I mean, consider the following two data definitions:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
import Data.Coerce

-- type role of `a` is "representational"
data Data1 a = Data1 a

-- type role of `a` is "nominal"
data Data2 a = Data2 (TypeFunction a)
type family TypeFunction x where
  TypeFunction Bool = Char
  TypeFunction _ = ()
```

Then, while it is true that `Coercible a b` entails `Coercible (Data1 a) (Data1 b)`, it does *not* entail `Coercible (Data2 a) (Data2 b)`. To make this concrete, load up the above in GHCi, then try:

```
ghci> newtype MyInt = My Int
ghci> let c1 = coerce :: (Data1 MyInt) -> (Data1 Int)
ghci> let c2 = coerce :: (Data2 MyInt) -> (Data2 Int) -- This doesn't work!
```

Unfortunately, there is no built-in constraint based way of enforcing that the role of a type variable is representational. You can make your own classes for this, as Edward Kmett [has done](https://github.com/ekmett/roles), but GHC doesn't automatically create instances of some of these classes the way class instances for `Coercible` are.

This led to [this](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/9123) trac ticket where they discuss the possibility of having a class `Representational f` with instances generated like for `Coercible` which could have things like

```
instance (Representational f, Coercible a b) => Coercible (f a) (f b)
```

If this was actually a thing today, all you would need in your constraint would be `Representational f`. Furthermore, as Richard Eisenberg observes on the ticket, we really ought to be able to figure out that `a` in `f a` has a representational role for any reasonable functor `f`. Then, we might not even need any constraint on top of `Functor f` as `Representational` could be a superclass of `Functor`.

[Here is a good discussion of the current limitations of roles.](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Roles2#join)

Answer (score 4):

Now that you have `QuantifiedConstraints`, I think you can do this:

```hs
type Parametric f = (forall a b. (Coercible a b => Coercible (f a) (f b)) :: Constraint)

newtype Foo = Foo Int

myFunction :: (Parametric f) => f Foo -> f Int
myFunction = coerce

test :: [Int]
test = myFunction [Foo 1, Foo 2, Foo 3]
```

This is nice, because an instance of `Parametric f` witnesses that `f` is an endofunctor on a category where the objects are types and a morphism between types `A` and `B` is an instance of `Coercible A B`.